# jquery overlape image with animation height

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm making some transitions in jquery and Im getting stuck. I want on click to overlape div with image in this div with red color background.

**HTML**

```
<div id="img_div1">
<img class="img" src=""  id="img" />
```

**CSS**

```
#img_div1
{
width:333px;
height:70px;
background:url("img/1.jpg");
}
```

`.img1{
    height:0px;
    width:333px;
}`

**jQuery**

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#img_div1").click(function (){
   $(".img1").animate({"height":"70px"},1000).attr("src", "http://gglys.com/images/logo.png");
    });
  });

**HERE IS MY CODE IN JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/24jsfbv8/

Answer (score 0):

The JSfiddle you posted was almost working. You just didn't have jQuery selected, and needed to change the "img" class in the html to "img1", like so:

```
<img class="img1" src=""  id="img" />
```

[Updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24jsfbv8/2/)